# Question titles overflow their column

Tags: bug, design

Long question titles (and their tags) extend to the left of the appropriate column:

[image]

The same behaviour can be observed on a number of sites. I suspect it's something to do with the new theme, but I'm not 100% certain.

Screenshot is from Chromium under Linux Mint Maya.

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 63.0a1.

Comment: what browser and in this case, screensize?

Comment: No repro on Windows 10, Firefox Quantum 61.0.2 (64-bit)